# Leaflet-canvas-markers cant set stroke

Tags: leaflet

[Leaflet-canvas-markers](https://github.com/lipton-ice-tea/leaflet-canvas-markers) is extending L.circleMarker.

And therefor it should be possible to set stroke to the L.canvasMarker(?).

Does someone know what im doing wrong, or what changes i need to make in leaflet-canvas-marker package to make it work?

Here is a jsfiddle; click on the circleMarker, it gets a thicker stroke. but if you click the canvasMarker it does not get anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/tq7nf3j2/

```
let marker1 = L.canvasMarker([58.970471,5.730373], {
    radius: 15,
    img: {
    url: 'img.png',
    size: [30,30]
    }
    }).addTo(map);


 marker1.on('click', function(e) {
    e.target.setStyle({weight: 10})
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `_updateImg(layer)` function to:

```
_updateImg(layer) {
            const { img } = layer.options;
            const p = layer._point.round();
            p.x += img.offset.x; p.y += img.offset.y;
            if (img.rotate) {
                this._ctx.save();
                this._ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
                this._ctx.rotate(img.rotate * Math.PI / 180);
                this._ctx.drawImage(img.el, -img.size[0] / 2, -img.size[1] / 2, img.size[0], img.size[1]);
                this._ctx.restore();
            } else {
              if(layer.options.stroke && layer.options.weight > 0){
                this._ctx.strokeStyle = layer.options.color; 
                this._ctx.lineWidth = layer.options.weight;    
              }
              this._ctx.drawImage(img.el, p.x - img.size[0] / 2, p.y - img.size[1] / 2, img.size[0], img.size[1]);
              if(layer.options.stroke && layer.options.weight > 0){
                this._ctx.strokeRect(p.x - img.size[0] / 2, p.y - img.size[1] / 2, img.size[0], img.size[1]);
              }
            }
        }
```

If you wan't that it works with `rotate` you have to copy it to the block above.
It's adding a rectangle with stroke behinde the image.

Also don't forgett to add `weight: 0` to the image, because circleMarkers have a default stroke of 3.

```
    let marker1 = L.canvasMarker([58.970471,5.730373], {
      radius: 15,
      img: {
        url: 'https://register.geonorge.no/symbol/files/tilgjengelighet/sittegruppe_positiv_groenn.png',
        size: [30,30]
      },
      weight: 0
    }).addTo(map);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/bLgd0opq/

Comment: Thanks! Works kinda well with geoman as well :D Only issue is snapping, which is not too bad